# AutoCAD installation required?

Tags: autocad

I am trying to create one sample AutoCAD app, in that i am trying to use  "MdiActiveDocument"

So my question is it a per-requisite that AutoCAD should be installed on client/user machine? to use my application? I am referring following reference dll's from "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014"

```
    "acdbmgd.dll",
    "acmgd.dll",
    "accoremgd.dll",
    "Autodeks.AutoCAD.Interop.dll",
    "Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AutoCAD (or RealDWG) must be installed on the user's machine.  As well, the add-on you're developing runs within the AutoCAD memory space so you'll want that to be located in an AutoCAD trusted directory.  It's also explicitly stated by Autodesk to NOT copy the AutoCAD dll files locally so remote execution really isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

1. If you want to create plug-ins especially for AutoCAD - yes, you have to install AutoCAD.
2. If you want to build server side app for manipulating dwg - no, you can do it with [RealDWG](http://www.autodesk.com/realdwg) or with [Teigha.NET](https://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/teigha_dot_net). Of course you can install AutoCAD on a server but you will be wasting money.